# How to show few correct bounding boxes instead of all detectiones in YOLOv3

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, bounding-box

This is my first YOLOv3 project to detect objects with 2 classes. In the resuls I am seeing plenty of detections. Is it possible to show only those boxes which has more than 70% (for example) accuracy or lets say top 3 boxes for each class? Would somebody please help?

my test is executed as follows:
`!./darknet detector test data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg ~/yolov3_custom_last.weights /content/5.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set 0.7 threshold value, if you want see only boxes which has more than 70% confidence score.

like this `!./darknet detector test data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg ~/yolov3_custom_last.weights /content/5.png -thresh 0.7`